# Why my noise texture is not same guru

Tags: shaders

[[image]]

[image]

Is there something wrong? It's like a durian[image]
https://pasteall.org/blend/53c0e115f7a64017883dc2069a8931ec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is pretty simple, your roughness in Noise Texture is set to 0, this way your donut is basically reflecting light and it looks really weird, set it to default 0.5 or even higher (the guy in the tutorial probably used an older version of Blender that didn't have roughness in Noise Texture
[image]

Btw, not sure if he says it, but you should add a aMapping node between Noise and texture coordinate

Comment: Thanks MikoCG! I solved the problem.